# "bimodule" on two ringed spaces and the tensor-hom adjunction of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, sheaf-theory

I saw the definition of bimodule and the tensor-hom adjunction on it: [the Tensor-Hom adjunction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction) , and the tensor-hom adjunction of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules: [Stacks01CN](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01CN)

Can the case of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules be considered as some kind of $(\mathscr{O}_X, \mathscr{O}_Y)$-modules and extended the tensor-hom adjunction to

$$
\mathcal{H o m}_{\mathcal{O}_X}\left(\mathcal{F} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} \mathcal{G}, \mathcal{H}\right) \longrightarrow \mathcal{Hom}_{{\mathcal{O}_Y}}\left(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{H o m}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{G}, \mathcal{H})\right)
$$

? What should be the definition for bimodule on ringed spaces? [Derived hom-tensor adjunction for $O_X$-modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4045320/derived-hom-tensor-adjunction-for-o-x-modules) seems related. Nevertheless it’s stated in more advanced language then I can understand.

Thank you very much